# findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0) Clarification

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding the source below:

```
myChar1 =  myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
System.out.println(myChar1);
myChar2 =  myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
System.out.print(myChar2);
```

I understand what it does, but I'm just having a bit of a trouble understanding how it works.
The actual prompting of the user for input is done at the first line right? but the real meaning of the first line is: "put the first char of input in myChar1". Then what happens? It seems the input still stays inside `myScanner` because when I use it in `myChar2` I get the second char, but why? why not the first `char`? Does `findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0)` deletes the char that is assigned to the variable?
And last question: if in the first line the program prompts the user for input why doesn't it do it again in the second line?
Also, a quick recap of the (".",0) would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the piece you are missing is that [`findWithinHorizon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) actually takes a regular expression as the String argument. In a regular expression, `.` matches any character (except a new line).

A call to `findWithinHorizon(".", 0)` simply finds the next character in the input and advances the Scanner past whatever was found.

So for example,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner("abc123");
for(;;) {
    String found = in.findWithinHorizon(".", 0);
    if(found == null) break;

    System.out.println(found);
}
```

the output is:

```
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

The reason it does not prompt for input at the second line is that is the way Scanner and System.in work together. They will only block and prompt for input if there is no more existing input to consume. As a short example, try this out:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    System.out.println(in.findWithinHorizon(".", 0));
}
```

That will loop infinitely, repeating back whatever you input, character by character. It will only prompt for more when it's done with the prior input. On the first iteration, Scanner will call `read` on System.in which will block and wait for input. When the input runs out, `read` will block again.